# avoid a watch to force filtering of data

Tags: angularjs, sorting, filter

I have an angular project using ui-router.  We have some controllers which set various filter/sorting values to modify our raw data.  In addition we have a number of views which can be plugged in which display the raw data in different manners.

I would like to have the plugged in views to be agnostic to the filter logic.  a filter runs when changes happen to filter controls, sets some filteredData variable, and the views all use the filteredData for display.  Any change to filtering updates filterData and forces the views to update.

As of now I have watches which detect when a filter/sort field is changed which run our filter method.  I know watches are best avoided, so how does one avoid using watches?  I essentially want to say "when filters are changed run filter and sort filters, when sort is changed run only sort filter"  Is there a better approach to tying dozens of controls to a single filter I want run?

Comment: You could use `$scope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on`, if you want to avoid $watches

Comment: @NewDev don't those suffer the same optimization and code cleanliest issues as a watch though?

Comment: Code cleanliness is subjective and definitely not something that could be assessed one way or the other by the content of your question. But the difference between these and `$watch` is that a watch is less-efficient, since it runs on every digest cycle, whereas `$broadcast`/`$on` is event-driven